# Modifying default Eclipse getters/setters behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse

On Eclipse Kepler, when you generate getters/setters (for java code), there is a box appearing where the default choice in "field access in declaring type" is "use getters and setters", but I always use the other option ("keep field reference") and I would like to make it default.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's hard-coded in the source. I had the same problem resolved by patching org.eclipse.jdt.ui{version}.jar:

- org\eclipse\jdt\internal\corext\refactoring\sef\SelfEncapsulateFieldRefactoring

changing in constructor `fEncapsulateDeclaringClass= true;` to `fEncapsulateDeclaringClass= false;`

- org\eclipse\jdt\internal\ui\refactoring\sef\SelfEncapsulateFieldInputPage

changing the method createFieldAccessBlock by setting `setSelected(true)` to the "keep reference" radio.